# display function not working while using OpenGL

Tags: c, sockets, opengl

i am trying to draw a line using OpenGL while the both end coordinates of the line are set in the idle function , but it is not getting drawn while I am sending the endpoint coordinates over the network using sockets.
below is the snap of the code

```
int  main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitWindowSize( 1024,1024);       /* A x A pixel screen window  */

glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
glutCreateWindow("Skeleton Tracker"); /* window title                   */
glutDisplayFunc(display);         /* tell OpenGL main loop what     */
glutIdleFunc(idle);

//first create the connection then we wil talk about the data transfer...
 /*****Code for server connection *****/

processRequest();
return 0;
}

void processrequest()
{
byte_sent = send(ClientSocket,(char*)&msg_pkt,sizeof(MSG_PACKET),0);
ofile<<"\nByte sent for start generating "<<byte_sent<<endl;
Sleep(1000);

memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));

glutMainLoop(); 
}

void display(void)
{
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     /* clear the window */
glColor3f ( 0.0, 1.0 , 0.0);       /* draw in light red */
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(x[0] , y[0]);
glVertex2f(x[1] , y[1]);
glEnd();

glEnd();
glFlush();

}


void idle(void)
{

printf("\nIn Idle function\n");

nRetVal = recv(ClientSocket , (char*)mainbuf , 192,0);

printf("\nAmount of data received : %d\n" , nRetVal);
memcpy(buf , mainbuf ,  sizeof(buf));   //buf is of 8 bytes to hold 2 floating nos.

memcpy( &x[p] ,buf , 4); // upto 3
x[p] = x[p]/10.0;

memcpy( &y[p] ,buf+4 , 4); //upto 7
y[p] = y[p]/10.0;

glutPostRedisplay();

  }
```

Comment: The programmer is always the BEST person to debug! Try stepping through or rather try putting `printf(..)` statements to analyse what are the values of `x[0]`, `y[0]` and so on. Just a piece of (unrelated) advice: Its always a good practice to do Network I/O on a different thread.. :)

Comment: @Thrustmaster The values are OK . I logged the values and then removed the code..its problem related to OpenGL not with the values.

Comment: What are the values? IIRC in this setup, the coordinates need to be within [-1,1]..

Comment: the successive values are : [-8.8 , 67.6] , [ -8.3 , 67] and BTW why the coordinates needs to be in range of -1,1

Comment: I have a bad bad memory of OpenGL. Can you try drawing with values in the range? I think you need a glScale*(..) in this case.. The problem, IMO, is that those coordinates are "out of your window"..

Comment: @Thrustmaster the problem is solved actually I was not setting  orthographic projection matrix(Though I don't know what it is used for .. , just got hint from another sample program...
Do tell if you have any idea regarding this , I set it using the instruction :
gluOrtho2D( -250, 250, -250, 250);
thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16482/discussion-between-javabinder-and-thrustmaster)

Comment: If you have already solved it, please answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks buddies for your time ... actually I forget to define the orthographic projection matrix before calling the glutMainloop ...

```
gluOrtho2D( -250, 250, -250, 250);
```

its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Design of your program is questionable - you have blocking recv() function in your idle function which is not good, idle should be as fast as possible to not affect your rendering.

consider creating one thread for rendering and the second thread for network communication, or at least use non-blockable recv() in your idle function to check whether there is any data on the socket available before reading (recv'ing) from it.

Comment: Appreciate your input. I think the design can vary depending upon the situation.In this case I am getting the coordinates of a line from the frame@30FPS so waiting time is 33ms which I think is enough for the idle function to take the control  from display function and process the data. ;)